# How can theta be so large on this option?

Tags: options

The AAPL Sep 95 put currently has a theta of -.21.  The put midpoint is .84.  84/21 = 4 days.  However, the put has nearly a month before expiration, at which time it will be zero.  Not 4 days from now.

What am I doing wrong or missing in the above calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I see a theta of -0.03ish. Delta is about the order of magnitude of your number, maybe you mixed them up?